# Using list generator for memory efficient code in Haskell

Tags: performance, list, haskell

I would like to get a handle on writing memory efficient haskell code. One thing I ran across is that there is no dead easy way to make python style list generators/iterators (that I could find).

Small example:

Finding the sum of the integers from 1 to 100000000 without using the closed form formula.

Python that can be done quickly with minimal use of memory as `sum(xrange(100000000)`. In Haskell the analogue would be `sum [1..100000000]`. However this uses up a lot of memory. I thought using `foldl` or `foldr` would be fine but even that uses a lot of memory and is slower than python. Any suggestions?

Comment: Haskell lists are *lazy*, which makes them closer to Python generators/iterators than Python lists, except that their interface looks like simple lists (because they are; Haskell is just a lazy language).

Comment: Compiled with -O2. Sum is implemented using folds in the source code. This sum allocates around 3 gb of memory and takes 1.8 seconds on my machine which is about 3x as long as long as python's `print sum(xrange(100000001))` which is why I was surprised. I thought laziness would fix the memory issue and that speed should be around equal. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Helix No lazyness makes it harder to understand space usage. Note that python has a very limited "lazyness". Sure generators produce one element at a time, however when doing a function call arguments are still evaluated before the call is performed. In Haskell arguments are *not* evaluated before the function call but only when, during the call, the value is needed. This means that chains of function call create big unevaluated structures.

Comment: *btw*: if compiled with `-O2` while `sum [...]` will allocate around 3gb in total yes - but not at the same time (it's `44,312 bytes maximum residency` on my system)

Comment: same with `foldl'` of course

Comment: does someone know how to avoid all the allocations in the back? I had a very quick look/go at it and even strict arguments, forced inlining and using `IORef` does not stop this

Comment: @Helix: Could you add your test program and your compiling options? Actually, both the python script and the Haskell program would be great. Note that your question "how to write memory efficient code" is rather broad.

Comment: to be sure, code your loops as recursive functions with `BangPatterns` and simple types (like `Int`), like this: `f n = go 0 0
  where go c !sum | c==n = sum+n | otherwise = go (c+1) (sum+c)`, `main = print $ f (100000000 :: Int)`. [On 32-bit it will cause integer overflow](http://ideone.com/5hQL3h) of couse.

Comment: @Zeta Sorry I don't believe that I can edit my own posts yet. My compiling options are pretty generic. Just `ghc --make -O2 $file -fglasgow-exts -fforce-recomp -threaded -rtsopts`. The code is `main = print $ sum [1..100000000]`. Changing to `Int` provides the best speedup and decreases memory usage. `foldl'` and `foldr` don't do much. The python code testing against is `print sum(xrange(100000001))` and run using the python command.

Comment: @Helix: Are you sure about that? [edit]ing is a [1 point privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-posts).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### TL;DR - I think the culprit in this case is - defaulting of GHC to `Integer`.

Admittedly I do not know enough about python, but my first guess would be that python switches to "bigint" only if necessary - therefore all calculations are done with `Int` a.k.a. 64-bit integer on my machine.

A first check with

```
$> ghci
GHCi, version 7.10.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> maxBound :: Int
9223372036854775807
```

reveals that the result of the sum (`5000000050000000`) is less than that number so we have no fear of `Int` overflow.

I have guessed your example programs to look roughly like this

### `sum.py`

```
print(sum(xrange(100000000)))
```

### `sum.hs`

```
main :: IO ()
main = print $ sum [1..100000000]
```

To make things explicit I added the type annotation `(100000000 :: Integer)`, compiling it with

```
$ > stack build --ghc-options="-O2 -with-rtsopts=-sstderr"
```

and ran your example,

```
$ > stack exec -- time sum
5000000050000000
   3,200,051,872 bytes allocated in the heap
         208,896 bytes copied during GC
          44,312 bytes maximum residency (2 sample(s))
          21,224 bytes maximum slop
               1 MB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)

                                     Tot time (elapsed)  Avg pause  Max pause
  Gen  0      6102 colls,     0 par    0.013s   0.012s     0.0000s    0.0000s
  Gen  1         2 colls,     0 par    0.000s   0.000s     0.0001s    0.0001s

  INIT    time    0.000s  (  0.000s elapsed)
  MUT     time    1.725s  (  1.724s elapsed)
  GC      time    0.013s  (  0.012s elapsed)
  EXIT    time    0.000s  (  0.000s elapsed)
  Total   time    1.739s  (  1.736s elapsed)

  %GC     time       0.7%  (0.7% elapsed)

  Alloc rate    1,855,603,449 bytes per MUT second

  Productivity  99.3% of total user, 99.4% of total elapsed

1.72user 0.00system 0:01.73elapsed 99%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 4112maxresident)k
```

and indeed the ~3GB of memory consumption is reproduced.

Changing the annotation to `(100000000 :: Int)` - altered the behaviour drastically

```
$ > stack build
$ > stack exec -- time sum
5000000050000000
          51,872 bytes allocated in the heap
           3,408 bytes copied during GC
          44,312 bytes maximum residency (1 sample(s))
          17,128 bytes maximum slop
               1 MB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)

                                     Tot time (elapsed)  Avg pause  Max pause
  Gen  0         0 colls,     0 par    0.000s   0.000s     0.0000s    0.0000s
  Gen  1         1 colls,     0 par    0.000s   0.000s     0.0001s    0.0001s

  INIT    time    0.000s  (  0.000s elapsed)
  MUT     time    0.034s  (  0.034s elapsed)
  GC      time    0.000s  (  0.000s elapsed)
  EXIT    time    0.000s  (  0.000s elapsed)
  Total   time    0.036s  (  0.035s elapsed)

  %GC     time       0.2%  (0.2% elapsed)

  Alloc rate    1,514,680 bytes per MUT second

  Productivity  99.4% of total user, 102.3% of total elapsed

0.03user 0.00system 0:00.03elapsed 91%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 3496maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+176minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

### For the interested

The behaviour of the haskell version does not change a lot if you use libraries like `conduit` or `vector` (both boxed and unboxed).

sample programs

`sumC.hs`

```
import Data.Conduit
import Data.Conduit.List as CL

main :: IO ()
main = do res <- CL.enumFromTo 1 100000000 $$ CL.fold (+) (0 :: Int)
          print res
```

`sumV.hs`

```
import           Data.Vector.Unboxed as V
{-import           Data.Vector as V-}

main :: IO ()
main = print $ V.sum $ V.enumFromTo (1::Int) 100000000
```

funny enough the version using

```
main = print $ V.sum $ V.enumFromN (1::Int) 100000000
```

is doing worse than the above - even though the [documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.11.0.0/docs/Data-Vector-Unboxed.html#g:11) says otherwise.

> ```
> enumFromN :: (Unbox a, Num a) => a -> Int -> Vector a
> ```
>
> O(n) Yield a vector of the given length containing the values x, x+1
>   etc. This operation is usually more efficient than enumFromTo.

### Update

@Carsten's comment made me curious - so I had a look into the sources for integer - well [`integer-simple`](https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/ghc-7.10/libraries/integer-simple) to be precise, because for `Integer` there exists other versions `integer-gmp` and `integer-gmp2` using `libgmp`.

```
data Integer = Positive !Positive | Negative !Positive | Naught

-------------------------------------------------------------------
-- The hard work is done on positive numbers

-- Least significant bit is first

-- Positive's have the property that they contain at least one Bit,
-- and their last Bit is One.
type Positive = Digits
type Positives = List Positive

data Digits = Some !Digit !Digits
            | None
type Digit = Word#

data List a = Nil | Cons a (List a)
```

so when using `Integer` there is quite a bit of memory overhead compared to `Int` or rather unboxed `Int#` - I guess as this should be optimized, (though I have not confirmed that).

So `Integer` is (if I calculate correctly)

- 1 x `Word` for the sum-type-tag (here `Positive`
- n x (`Word + Word`) for `Some` and the `Digit` part
- 1 x `Word` for the last `None`

a memory overhead of *(2 + floor(log_10(n))* for each `Integer` in that calculation + a bit more for the accumulator.

Comment: wow interesting - I can understand the difference in time but the difference in memory consumption is puzzling me

Comment: @Carsten I tried to answer your question too - but I am not sure if everything is correct, I am by no means expert on that topic

Comment: @epsilonhalbe: IIRC, `integer-gmp` uses something along `data Integer = Positive !ByteStuff# | Negative !ByteStuff# | SmallInt !Int#`. So for small integers, it _should_ perform the same as `Int`, but the checks whether `(+)` needs more space than `Int#` provides probably take their additional toll (and I'm not sure of the conditions that switch to `Positive` from `SmallInt`).